# How to show pictures one after another (vertically or horizontally) in ipython in a cell?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
for i in range(4):
    img = X_train[(int)((n_train-1)/(i+1)),:,:,:]
    plt.imshow(img)
```

When I run this code, the result will be like below. It shows only one pic.

How to show the 4 pics together(one after another vertically or horizontally). Thanks
[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `show()` for each plot. Without the `show()` method, ipython only shows the last image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
for i in range(4):
    img = np.random.rand(10,10)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```

results in

[image]